# pass ENUM(CustomType) to Another Class, where that ENUM doesn't exist

Tags: c#

//question update

Let's say, for my new project, I create a file, where I have:

```
namespace A{
    public enum MyDates{
       19a,
       19b,
       19c,
       .....
    }

    ....

    public class  MyABC : Transaction{

        ....
        string smth = MyFunc(MyDates.19a);
        ....
    }
}
```

I have my custom library-file (let's say same, or different namespace), which I also include in my every projects and fill it with new methods according to my needs. Now, I want to add another method there, that can be called only whenever I need to pass `MyDates` type:

```
namespace A{

    partial class Transaction{
      ......

      public string MyFunc(MyDates smth){ 
            return (smth == MyDates.19a ? 'Hi' : (smth == MyDates.19b ? ( etc... ) ) )  ; 
      }

      ......
    }
}
```

However, namespace `B` won't compile (because `MyDates` doesnt exist there).  I never call that method without that ENUM, and why it still requires me to define that enum within its namespace again? `MyDates` is dynamic and can be changed (removed some values), and I don't want to modify my library every time.

Comment: You need to add a reference to A and a _using A;_ inside the library B. But something in your requirements is odd. An enum is not something dynamic that you can change without leaving the code that use it unaffected.

Comment: 19a etc are not valid names for an enum

Comment: this "another file" - is it another file in the same assembly? or: another assembly?

Comment: @MarcGravell in the same assembly, if I correctly understand (i am a bit newbie to C#).

Comment: @T.Todua if it is the same assembly, then ... the only thing you're missing is a `using` directive to import that namespace, which ctrl+. will usually fix for you. There is no "modify my library every time" concern if they are in the same library.

Comment: @Steve i've updated question.. thnx.

Answer (score 1):

> MyDates is a dynamic and can be changed (removed some values) and i dont want to modify my library everytime.

The only way to achieve that with an `enum` is for the consuming code to **only** access the `enum` via reflection (`Enum.GetNames()` / `Enum.GetValues()`), and not rely on the values that existed at compile-time. This can be done, but suggests that maybe an `enum` is not the best choice for this data, especially if you are removing items. Removing members is inherently a change that can break consumers.

Comment: sorry, i considered to fully update my question.. you can revise. thanks

Comment: @T.Todua it sounds like you're missing either a library/project reference, or a `using` directive - simple as that

Comment: but there are cases, when I wont use the Parent project (which contains that ENUM), but my library will be included in other projects too (which projects wont contain that ENUM). So, what will happen then? why I cannot set an argument for method, which argument type is only used in specific project only?

sorry for my bad explanation, but i think you understand now my problem. THANKS!

Comment: @T.Todua any code that uses that method must have access to the type definition of all types used in the parameters of all overloads